# Angular2 RC4 debounceTime still calls on every keystroke

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a validation directive that checks to see if a client key is unique.  Everything seems to work as expected until I check the network traffic and see that it is making a call for every keystroke.

```
import { Directive, forwardRef, ReflectiveInjector } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/common';
import { FormControl, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {DomainService} from '../services/domain.service';

interface IRefIdValidator {
}

function validateRefIdFactory(domainService : DomainService) {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<IRefIdValidator> => {

    // get the domain Id and Ref Id key 
    let domainId: number = +control.root.find('domainId').value;
    let clientId: number = +control.root.find('clientId').value;
    let key: string = control.value;

    // Return an observable with null if the
    // reference id check comes back successful
    return new Observable((obs: any) => {
      control
        .valueChanges
        .debounceTime(500)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .flatMap(value => domainService.checkDomainClientKey(domainId, clientId, key))
        .subscribe(
        data => {
          obs.next(null);
          obs.complete();
        },
        error => {
          obs.next({ refId: true });
          obs.complete();
        }
        );
    });
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[validateRefId][formControlName],[validateRefId][ngModel],[validateRefId][formControl]',
  providers: [
    DomainService, 
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => RefIdValidatorDirective), multi: true }
  ]
})
export class RefIdValidatorDirective {
  validator: Function;

  constructor(
    private domainService: DomainService
    ) {
      console.log('RefIdValidatorDirective created');
    this.validator = validateRefIdFactory(this.domainService);
  }

  validate(c: AbstractControl) {
    return this.validator(c);
  }
}
```

I am using this validation directive in a model driven form:

```
 this.domainForm = this.fb.group({
      clientKey: ['', Validators.required, new RefIdValidatorDirective(this.domainService).validator]
    });
```

As you can see, this isn't efficient either as I am passing the domainService from the parent component to the validation directive, however, I have been unable to figure out how to get the service injected into this directive any other way.

Here is what my network trace looks like, even though I am typing fast:

```
24?key=Test
24?key=TestA
24?key=TestAB
24?key=TestABC
```

Any help with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in your code: you aren't returning an `Observable`, but instead a `Subscription` because you are subscribing and returning.

To do it, it's better to create s `Subject` to debounce each keystroke. Here's a good practice that you can adapt to your needs. The `onSearch` method is called for each keystroke:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({...})
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 private searchTermStream = new Subject<string>();
 private searchSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchSubscription = this.createInputSubscriber();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.searchTermStream.complete();
  }

  onSearch(query: string): void {
    this.searchTermStream.next(query);
  }

  private createInputSubscriber(): Subscription {
    return this.searchTermStream
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .debounceTime(500)
      .subscribe((query: string) => console.log(query));
  }
}
```

Here we also clean up the memory in the `ngOnDestroy` method when the component is destroyed.